# Geneva-based STS, Java interop

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services, geneva-framework

I'd like to test whether my Geneva-based fedearated security services can be consumed with NetBeans/WSIT. Is there something like step-by-step guide? Server side uses 'message credentials over HTTPS' security mode while all the examples I've seen rely on message-level encryption and focus on consuming .net STS from Java RP-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links.

[mszCool: Identity Interoperability - Geneva Beta 1 STS with .NET Client and Netbeans 6.5 / Metro 1.3 / WSIT / Java client working.](http://blogs.msdn.com/mszcool/archive/2009/01/23/identity-interoperability-geneva-beta-1-sts-with-net-client-and-netbeans-6-5-metro-1-3-wsit-java-client-working-again.aspx).

[The WSIT Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/index.html).

[WSIT Documentation: Security Mechanisms](https://wsit-docs.dev.java.net/releases/1.1/ahicu.html#ahicx):

> However, the message security
>   mechanisms require a newer version of
>   certificates than is available with
>   GlassFish. You can download valid
>   keystore and truststore files for the
>   client and server as described in [To Manually Update GlassFish Certificates](https://wsit-docs.dev.java.net/releases/1.1/ahidm.html#gfrgz).
>
> To use this mechanism, follow the steps in [Configuring SSL For Your Applications](https://wsit-docs.dev.java.net/releases/1.1/ahidh.html#ahidi).
>
> See Also: [Example: Transport Security (SSL)](https://wsit-docs.dev.java.net/releases/1.1/ahiei.html#ahiep).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah, I've seen first two of these links, and, as I've already said, we were able to run Java relying party service with Geneva STS, as well as consume Java services with Java clients. I have also learned about truststores and talking to SSL-protected endpoints in Java. Our only porblem is specific scenario when Java client talks to .net RP-services. The errors we get are rather cryptic, so I was hoping there's working sample that we could use as starting line.